# JSON to custom object

Tags: javascript, node.js

In C# I have used NewtonSoft.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialise a complex JSON object into custom C# Objects. The JSON is actually carved up into different objects, its not a 1-1 relationship.

Is there an equivalent way to do this with Javascript?

The examples I've seen appear simplistic like:

```
function Foo(a, b)
{
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
}
```

Is there a better way than doing something like this?

```
function Foo(a, b)
{
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   this.loadFromJson = function() {code...};
   this.saveToJson = function() {code...};
}
```

Edit:
I know I can use json.parse functionality to load the JSON data into an object but that’s a 1:1 relationship.

The c# code I am converting loads a complex json payload from a REST endpoint then deserializes that into different classes which are effectively different views of the data.

Comment: you mean inbuild methods like `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Json format can contain only data (dictionaries, arrays, and primitive types). Objects with methods are not supported by design

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: Not really, and it's not really needed.